# Android and playing SVG animation

Tags: android, animation, svg

I'm writing an Android application and I'd like to play a simple SVG animation. I'm aware that Android does not offer SVG support; what are my options here?

Comment: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/10/first-look-at-animated-vector-drawable.html

Answer (score 14):

Starting from Android Lollipop (API level 21) it is possible to implement using [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).

There are also tools that will help to animate vector drawable  [shapeshifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) and blog post from the author of the tool shapeshifter [An Introduction to Icon Animation Techniques](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html).

Answer (score 9):

1. Take your SVG image and convert it to a VectorDrawable [here](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)
2. Add your downloaded XML file to your project and see how it looks. Heres an example of an VectorDrawable prepared for a rotation and path morph animation:

   ```
   <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:width="64dp"
    android:viewportHeight="600"
    android:viewportWidth="600" >
    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="300.0"
        android:pivotY="300.0"
        android:rotation="45.0" >
        <path
            android:name="v"
            android:fillColor="#000000"
            android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
    </group>
   ```

3 Now create a AnimatedVectorDrawable where you refer to the rotationGroup and path morph in the created VectorDrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/vectordrawable">
   <target android:name="rotationGroup" android:animation="@anim/rotation" />
   <target android:name="v" android:animation="@anim/path_morph" />
</animated-vector>
```

4 Create two animators for the AnimatedVectorDrawable:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="6000"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="360" />
```

and :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z"
        android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
        android:valueType="pathType"/>
 </set>
```

(It is also possible to define all this in one file, refer to the [docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html))

One way to then start the animation is by getting the drawable from the view and run `start()`.

Comment: Is there a lesson on how we can understand svg path? And its values?

Comment: @RoCkVangeance the lesson is that Google is trying to reinvent the wheel. Why not support natively svg (and css for animations), which are a standard, instead of <vector> and <objectAnimator> which are Android-specific ? Answer Google, the people want to know !

Comment: As the site linked to in 1 (nicely without ads) will tell you:
This tool has been deprecated. Use official Vector Asset Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use VectorDrawable. if target is under Lollipop use [support library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html).