# Adding a animated SVG to Android Fragment

Tags: android, animation, svg

I have seen many many questions with this theme. For example
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115696/android-and-playing-svg-animation). But nothing I found worked.

I want to add my own loading animation and I have a SVG file with this animation that works perfect in Chrome.

It doesn't have to be a nice solution it just has to work. 
Do you have any ideas? 
Did I missed Something? If it helpf I can also add the svg file.

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and playing SVG animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115696/android-and-playing-svg-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the available SVG libraries for Android support animation at this time.

Right now you have two choices.

1. If your SVG is simple enough, convert it to a VectorDrawable, and then to an AnimatedVectorDrawable. You might find [ShapeShifter](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/ShapeShifter) helpful in this process.
2. Use a `WebView` and display your SVG in that.

Comment: Thank you, The WebView solution sounds good for me, do you now a good tutorial for this ?

Comment: No. I don't have anything I can recommend other than the Android documentation.

Comment: I used the Android documentation and now I have a nice Result, Thank you so much