# how to play .svg animation file android activity

Tags: android, svg, android-animation

I have an animated *.svg file. I cannot find a way to play it in my android activity. I also need to know when the loop is over. 
how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and playing SVG animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115696/android-and-playing-svg-animation)

Answer (score 3):

You could use https://shapeshifter.design/ in order to create an AnimatedVectorDrawable from plain SVG (see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable)

After creating the drawable and including it to the Assets Folder you can load the drawable and assing it to an ImageView, which is defined in your xml Layout.

See the following code:

```
final AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVectorDrawableCompat =
            AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.animatedvector);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(animatedVectorDrawableCompat);

    final Animatable animatable = (Animatable) imageView.getDrawable();
    animatable.start();
```

`R.drawable.animatedvector` is the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` you want to load, while `R.id.imageView` is the ImageView, which should show the `AnimatedVectorDrawable`.

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I got issue: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.isStateful()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.isStateful(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:397)