# Is there a way to load online animated svg image in android?

Tags: android, animation, svg, android-glide

Now I am using GIF to load animations from back end. I would like to reduce network traffic and start using animated SVG.

Is there a way to achieve that? Tried to google it, but did not found any actual answer.

For image loading I am using Glide.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733140/7319704

and you can use Lottie animation

Comment: Thanks, but I need to load it from online source, not from local resources.

Comment: you can ask for php guy can he send svg images and you can convert into vector drawable

Comment: That is a point of loading images externally so it could be changed dynamically without updating whole app when want to change or add single image.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I would like to load animated (pixel independant, like SVG) images from an URL and show them in an app.

Comment: There is only option to use Glide and do customization, try to google it. I gave up