# How to convert an animated svg file into an animated-vector drawable?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have an .svg file with  properties for loading animation.

I'm trying to convert this into a form that can be used in android UI.

Yet it seems that svg converter in Android Studio just converts this svg file into a static vector drawable, without animation.

Is there any way to convert this file smoothly into an animated vector drawable?

Comment: continue with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115696/android-and-playing-svg-animation