# How to replicate LinkedIn loading animation in android studio?

Tags: java, android, css-animations, android-animation

The following is the `css` and `html` of `LinkedIn` loading animation. How to replicate this animation in android studio in xml?

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition:2s
}
.wrapper img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
.cover{
    position:relative;
    width:130px;
    height:5px;
    background:#d3d3d3;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-top:75px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:2s
}
.cover:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:68px;
    height:5px;
    left:-30px;
    background:#1e90ff;
    border-radius:20px;
    animation:link 1s infinite ease;
    transition:1s
}
@keyframes link{
    50%{
        left:96px
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="cover"></div></div>
```

I tried to extract animation frames and put them inside `animation-list` as follows:

```
<!-- loading.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="<http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_color"/>
    <item android:bottom="50dp" android:gravity="bottom">
        <animation-list android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="100" />
        <animation-list android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="100" />
        <animation-list android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="100" />
        <animation-list android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="100" />
        <animation-list android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="100" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But I want a direct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with help of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9115696/6576302) and [shapeshifter](https://beta.shapeshifter.design/) I ended up with the following animation:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData="M 24 4 L 48 10 L 0 10 L 0 14 Z"
                android:fillColor="#0C53CC"
                android:strokeColor="#f09090"
                android:strokeWidth="0"
                android:strokeLineCap="square"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="1000"
                android:valueFrom="M -20 14 L -20 10 L 4 10 L 4 14 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 20 14 L 20 10 L 48 10 L 48 14 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:repeatCount="infinite"
                android:repeatMode="reverse"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

[image]